# How to change priority of integration test in selenium python

Tags: python, django, selenium, integration-testing, django-testing

Example of my test case

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
...

class CustomerTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(CustomerTest, cls).setUpClass()
        ...

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(CustomerTest, cls).tearDownClass()
        ...

    def setUp(self):
        super(CustomerTest, self).setUp()
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CustomerTest, self).tearDown()
        ...

    def test_create(self):
        print("A")

    def test_search(self):
        print("B")
```

Result : `AB`

The issue found here was that, when I change piority of my test, It won't change result

```py
   def test_search(self):
       print("B")

   def test_create(self):
       print("A")
```

Result still : `AB`

Expected result : `BA`

So, how can I change priority of my testcase in intergration test

Comment: Try to modify as : test_1_search , test_2_create

Comment: I have try it before have this question. But I just ask for better way. Because ordername of testcase is not formal way. I think so